# Compatibility - Spring Security 4.2.2 with Spring 3.2.14

Tags: spring, spring-security

our application currently uses JBoss Portal with JAAS as the authentication/authorization mechanism.  The version of Spring we are currently using is 3.2.14.  For various reasons we are unable to upgrade Spring right now.

We are going to be migrating to Spring Security shortly and are wondering if Spring Security 4.2.2 will be compatible with Spring 3.2.14.  My thoughts are that since Spring Security is a separate project it should be OK?

I can't seem to find any information on the compatibility issues between major versions of Spring and major versions of Spring Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring Security 4.2.2, the minimum recommended Spring version is **4.3.5**.

This is stated in the `SpringSecurityCoreVersion` class which is located in the `org.springframework.security.core` package.